# android: Update data in the Sqlite Database

Tags: android

I been trying to update the data in my sqLite database but when I click the update button it will only go back to the previous page and nothing change with the data theirs no error in my codes..please check my codes thank you.

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public void updateData(long rowId, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase )
    {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_QUESTION, new_question);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER1, new_ans1);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER2, new_ans2);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER3, new_ans3);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER4, new_ans4);

       // String selection = AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ + " LIKE ?";
        //String[] selection_arg = {new_question};
       sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID + "=" + rowId, null);


    }

my Update class:

 public void updateData(View view)
    {
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

        question = New_Question.getText().toString();
        ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
        ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
        ans3 = New_Ans3.getText().toString();
        ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();
long rowId = 0;
        helper.updateData(rowId,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in updating values to db table. Then i tried below code. It works fine for me
Try this code.

**DatabaseHelper class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
Context context;

// change your database details here;

String db_name = "Database name";
String db_version = "Databse version";
String tbl_name = "Table name";
int col_row_id = "row id col";
String col_question = "Question col name";
String col_ans_1 = "answer 1 col";
String col_ans_2 = "answer 2 col";
String col_ans_3 = "answer 3 col";
String col_ans_4 = "answer 4 col";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, db_name, null, db_version);

        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "create table " + tbl_name+ "(" +
                int_col_row+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                col_question+ " text, "+
                col_ans_1+ " text, "+
                col_ans_2+ " text, "+
                col_ans_3+ " text, "+
                col_ans_4+ " text, "+
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        String query = "drop table if exists "+tbl_name;
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void updateData(int rowId, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4) {
        String query = "update "+tbl_name+ " set "+
        col_question+"=\""+new_question+"\","+
        col_answer1+"=\""+answer1+"\","+
        col_answer2+"=\""+answer2+"\","+
        col_answer3+"=\""+answer3+"\","+
        col_answer4+"=\""+answer4+"\""+
        " where "+col_row_id+"=\""+rowId+"\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);

        db.close();
    }
}
```

**Update class**

```
public class update{

 // initialise New_Question, New_Ans1, New_Ans2, New_Ans3, New_Ans4 as final variables. Also set onclick function of buttion to updateData

public void updateData(View view){
      helper = new DatabaseHelper(view.getContext());

      String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

       question = New_Question.getText().toString();
        ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
        ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
        ans3 = New_Ans3.getText().toString();
        ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();
       int rowId = 0;

       helper.updateData(rowId,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4);
}

}
```

Comment: sir your codes is no error but the data still won't update please check my update class if their an error Sir. when I click the update button it will only go back in the previous page Thank you  sir.

Comment: I have updated my code. Please try this. You should initialise correctly all variables. Also try to log each line and check where code gets breaked

Comment: Sir Ijas Ahamed, Please help me. Is there any link you know on how to view the data from Sqlite to Button or Textview.? I can't start my qiuz project on how to play with randomize questions. Please I need your help..

Comment: Sorry for delay for my reply. Please checkout this link. https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=278&video=27387 . I mostly use newboston tutorials for any problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about long, but I used this code to update String value, 
Try this code in DatabaseHelper class:
`return sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID=?,newString[] {rowId});`
instead of:
`sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID + "=" + rowId, null);`

Comment: sir what should i put in "?" and newString[] because they remain red as error Sir.

Comment: `return sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID + "=" + rowId);` I think it will update long datatype value.