# Android: Update

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been working with my App which is the the Android Quiz. This app can add, delete, search, view and update data. Update is the only problem I have. Before the user can  update, users will only search for the Id of the Data then it will load on the EditText, and when I click the update button, Toast message will only show "Successfully Updated" but the data on the sqlite nothing happened or change. Please check my codes thank you so much.

My DatabaseHelper class:

Create Table:

```
 private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ+"("+ AdminContact.Question.ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_QUESTION+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER1+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+ AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER2+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+ AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER3+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+ AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER4+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

My update:

```
public void updateData(long ID, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_QUESTION, new_question);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER1, new_ans1);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER2, new_ans2);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER3, new_ans3);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER4, new_ans4);


        sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID + "=" + ID, null);

        return;
    }
```

My Update class:

```
    EditText Search_Id, New_Question, New_Ans1, New_Ans2, New_Ans3, New_Ans4;
    DatabaseHelper helper;
    String SearchID, NewId, NewQuestion, NewAns1, NewAns2, NewAns3, NewAns4;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    TextView title_text;
    Button updateButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_contact);
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Search_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_search);
        New_Question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_question);
        New_Ans1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans1);
        New_Ans2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans2);
        New_Ans3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans3);
        New_Ans4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans4);
        title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        New_Question.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        title_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        updateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }

    public void searchContact(View view) {

    SearchID = Search_Id.getText().toString();
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = helper.getData(SearchID, sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        NewQuestion = cursor.getString(0);
        NewAns1 = cursor.getString(1);
        NewAns2 = cursor.getString(2);
        NewAns3 = cursor.getString(3);
        NewAns4 = cursor.getString(4);
        NewId = SearchID;

        New_Question.setText(NewQuestion);
        New_Ans1.setText(NewAns1);
        New_Ans2.setText(NewAns2);
        New_Ans3.setText(NewAns3);
        New_Ans4.setText(NewAns4);
        New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        title_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        updateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}


public void updateData(View view)
{
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

    question = New_Question.getText().toString();
    ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
    ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
    ans3 = New_Ans3.getText().toString();
    ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();

    int ID = 0;
    helper.updateData(ID,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();

}
```

Comment: No need to create DatabaseHelper instance in each function as you have already created one in OnCreate(). @Jun'z

Comment: Are you sure the update is really success? Have you check the return value of `sqLiteDatabase.update`?

Comment: Sir zdd, I can't tell if it is really success I see no error on the logcat. Is there any you can add or suggest sir???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: Update data in the Sqlite Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645913/android-update-data-in-the-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'update' statement

> sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID + "=" + ID, null);

you want to update only rows with matching ID.

So each time you execute the following lines in your updateData() method

> int ID = 0;
>
> helper.updateData(ID,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);

you are updating the row with ID = 0.

To find out whether you updated anything you can check the return value of the `sqLiteDatabase.update()` method: it will give you the number of updated rows.

See also this [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Sir 0X0nosugar, by using this "ID = 0." what should I use sir instead??? please sir..

Comment: @Jun'z - I suppose you have more than one question (=row) in your database, and your database identifies the questions by looking at the row id. So when you read one specific question from the db, you have to *keep the row ID in some variable* and use this variable for accessing the same question at a later time.

Comment: Sir do you have any links on how to make a android quiz??? please help thank  you

Comment: @Jun'z - please stop calling people 'Sir' when on SO. It is okay or even necessary elsewhere but it does not belong here. About the quiz link: I found something on [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-create-a-simple-quiz-game-for-Android), maybe it's useful :)